# Finding out on what days were most purchases

Tags: mysql, database, time

Given the following set up, for each `CD_name`, how can I find out which days had the most purchases. My result table should list the `CD_no`, and the date of the day (with alias 'Busiest). A CD can appear severale times in the result table if there were severals days that they have been purchased an equal amount, and so sort the result table by the `CD_no` alphabetically, and for the same CD_no, sort by date with the earliest first.

```
CREATE TABLE CD 
(
  CD_no TINYINT UNSIGNED,
  genre VARCHAR(60),
  purchase_date DATE NOT NULL,
  publication_time TIME NOT NULL,
  Artist VARCHAR(20)
);
```

### Edit

The expected output lists the CD_number and the date of the day which was busiest, also a CD number can appear on several days that had equal amounts of purchases.

For example with the following data:

```
CD_No   purchase_date    
1        2012-07-09
1        2012-07-09
1        2012-07-09
1        2012-07-10
1        2012-07-10
2        2012-11-11
2        2012-11-11
2        2012-11-12
2        2012-11-12
```

Should have the result table of:

```
CD_NO      Busiest
1        2012-07-09
2        2012-11-11
2        2012-11-12
```

Because cd_no 1 has most sales on that date, and cd_no 2 had joint purchases.

Answer (score 2):

```
select CD_no,
       purchase_date as busiest
from CD
group by CD_no, purchase_date 
order by count(purchase_date) desc,
         CD_no asc,
         purchase_date asc
limit 3
```

Comment: This did not work, instead of giving me a count of the purchase dates, i need the dates of which there was the most purchases were made on.

I need to find out which days had the most purchases on them. My result table should like the Cd_No and the date of the day with busiest alias.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output description to your question.

Comment: The expected output lists the CD_number and the date of the day which was busiest, also a CD number can appear on several days that had equal amounts of purchases.

For example with the following data:
CD_No   purchase_date    
1        2012-07-09
1        2012-07-09
1        2012-07-09
1        2012-07-10
1        2012-07-10
2        2012-11-11
2        2012-11-11
2        2012-11-12
2        2012-11-12

Should have the result table of:
CD_NO      Busiest
1        2012-07-09
2        2012-11-11
2        2012-11-12

Because cd_no 1 has most sales on that date, and cd_no 2 had joint purchases.

Comment: This returns difference dates, of the same CD_no, it should only return one cd_no, and its corrosponding busiest purchase dates (ie the most purchases on a given day), and only returns more than one if there is an equal amount on two different days which both are the max.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/406c1/6/0)

```
create view purchases as
select cd_no, purchase_date, count(*) as purchases
from cd
group by cd_no, purchase_date;

select p1.cd_no, p1.purchase_date as busiest
from purchases p1
join (select cd_no, max(purchases) as purchases
      from purchases
      group by cd_no) as p2
      on p1.cd_no = p2.cd_no and p1.purchases = p2.purchases
order by p1.cd_no, p1.purchase_date;
```